# How to get current url user is in .jsp file using javascript or java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, url, jstl

I want to compare current url the user is in, and if it equals 3 different urls, it should write a certain meta tag , if not it should write another meta tag. But when i write my javascript it writes all the code as a string instead of executing

So i this is what i tried  inside the .jsp file

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href == ("https://www.farmers.com/sitemap/"||"https://www.farmers.com/contact-us/send-message/" || "https://www.farmers.com/payments/") ) {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">');
    } else {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">');
    }
</script>
```

when i see view page source i get , it never executes

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href == ("https://www.farmers.com/sitemap/"||"https://www.farmers.com/contact-us/send-message/" || "https://www.farmers.com/payments/") ) {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">');
    } else {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">');
    }
</script>
```

I want to be able to determine what url im in , and once the user checks view page source they can see a certain meta tag for the certain url they are in . 
Should this be written in java or javascript ? 
how do i get the javascript to execute and write to the view page source ?

this is my jsp file

```
<%--

  ==============================================================================

  headlibs.jsp includes the scripts and css to be included in the head tag.

  ==============================================================================

--%><%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%><%
%>

<cq:includeClientLib css="falcon.base.bootstrap.rwd"/>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href == ("https://www.farmers.com/sitemap/"||"https://www.farmers.com/contact-us/send-message/" || "https://www.farmers.com/payments/") ) {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">');
    } else {
        document.write('<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">');
    }
</script>



<script language="javascript1.2" src="/etc/designs/falcon/rwd/clientlibs_base/js/at.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/falcon/rwd/clientlibs_base/js/respond.js">  
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to compare each string implicitly. Also bots may not execute javascript so your meta shouldn't be in javascript.

Comment: but its writing my whole script section as a string, once i see view page source , I need to encapsulate my javascript with something

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this to work in modern browsers then you can do this...

["https://www.farmers.com/sitemap/","https://www.farmers.com/contact-us/send-message/","https://www.farmers.com/payments/"].includes(window.location.href);

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes for a polyfill for older browsers.

You can also do the use the following code if you don't want to deal with a polyfill:

["https://www.farmers.com/sitemap/","https://www.farmers.com/contact-us/send-message/","https://www.farmers.com/payments/"].join('').indexOf("https://www.farmers.com/payments/");

Once that's in place though I think you'll quickly realize that there a bunch of edge cases that this type of basic check doesn't account for... You'll probably end up asking other questions about RegEx or pattern matching.

Comment: my problem is not the javascript logic , but when i put any javascript inside my .jsp file . It actually prints the whole javascript code including the <script></script> as a string